# What can I do when I keep exceeding memory used while using Dask-ML

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, dask, dask-distributed

I am using Dask-ML to run some code which uses quite a bit of RAM memory during training. The training dataset itself is not large but it's during training which uses a fair bit of RAM memory. I keep getting the following error message, even though I have tried using different values for `n_jobs`:

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
```

What can I do?

Ps: I have also tried using Kaggle Kernel (which allows up to 16GB RAM) and this didn't work. So I am trying Dask-ML now. I am also just connected to the Dask cluster using its default parameter values, with the code below:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import joblib

client = Client()

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    # My own codes
```

Comment: You could purchase more memory.

Comment: Thanks @orlp, but I am looking for a way where I don't have to pay. Do you know of any other free notebooks or have a free trial version? I have already tried Colab and it didn't work.

Comment: You probably don't want to use the Dask joblib backend on a single machine. As https://ml.dask.org/joblib.html says, joblib already provides single-machine parallelism. The Dask joblib backend is primarily useful for clusters.

Comment: Thanks @TomAugspurger. With my `dask.distributed` code above, am I not connected to a Dask cluster already (rather than connected to just a single machine like what you said in your post)? If my code is not properly connected to a cluster, could you tell me where in the code I need to change? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Dask has a detailed page on techniques to help with [memory management](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/memory.html).  You might also be interested in [configuring spilling to disk Dask workers](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#memory-management).  For example, rather